# Python - Chat in Minecraft server through Sockets/Packets?

Tags: python, sockets, tcp, minecraft, packets

I've spent a lot of time using different libraries and attempting to connect to a Minecraft server listening on the port 25565 to send packets that could show up in the chat.
So far, I've had no success. The only instance where I was able to do this was only within my own LAN, but no one else could see the chat messages.

Is there anyway to authenticate Minecraft through Python and send a chat packet to the server and 25565 port? Obviously I wouldn't be able to be online while opening the socket because you can only have one connection on the same IP and port at a time until it's closed.

Probably the most staight-forward version of the code I have is here:

---

```
from __future__ import absolute_import

import socket
import select
import sys
import atexit
import os
import codecs
import platform
import base64

soc = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

address = '<EXAMPLE ADDRESS HERE>'
port = 25565

print(address)
print(port)

try:
    soc.connect((address, port))
    print('Successful connection to server!')
    try:
        soc.sendall(b"Hello, I am a TCP Socket!")
        print('(Successfully sent message to the server)')
        data = soc.recv(1024)
        dc = data.decode('utf-8')
        soc.close()
    except Exception as e:
        print('Failed!')
        print(e.message)
except Exception as e:
    print('Failed to connect')
```

Comment: *"you can only have one connection on the same IP and port at a time"*. Really?

Comment: I was under the impression that if this was possible, it would be with a single connection. Is there an alternative? Thanks.

Comment: Your TCP client uses a dynamically allocated port on its side, so from a TCP perspective you can have many connections to a singe port on a server - each one has a unique client side port.

Comment: see wiki.vg. Your client needs to login first, and do some more stuff. Note that the packets have a specific format, so you should work on that first. Or you could use a python library if there's one.

Comment: Look at [wiki.vg](http://wiki.vg/Main_Page), and consider using [quarry](https://github.com/barneygale/quarry) as well; it's a python lib that'll help.